# Different results from Registry.GetValue() and Registry.User.GetValue()

Tags: c#, registry

I'm getting different results in `output1` and `output2`. While the first one gives me the value I actually see in the registry, the latter only gives me the default value. What do I miss?

```
String output1 = Registry.GetValue(
  @"HKEY_USERS\blobb", "beep", "nope!") as String;

String output2 = Registry.Users.GetValue(
  @"blobb\beep", "nope!") as String;
```

I've tried quite a few different variation of the input string but none gave me the corrrect value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Registry.Users.GetValue` is looking for a value named 'blobb\beep' in the root USERS key

To get the same result as your first example, you need something like

```
using (var blobb = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey("blobb"))
{
    String output2 = blobb.GetValue("beep", "nope!") as String
}
```

Comment: It seems to me more straight-forward to go with `Registry.GetValue()` approach **but** the problem is that the path of the key I'm trying to access has a nasty number right after "*HKEY_USERS*" and that number varies between different computers. Is there a general way on how to access e.g. "*HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-12345678\Software\Microsoft*"? Although the number vary, the rest is the same for "all" computers...

Comment: Have a look at using HKEY_CURRENT_USER\blobb instead

Comment: Do you mean skipping the nasty number altogether?

Comment: Absolutely, assuming the nasty number is the current user, you can use "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\blah" instead of "HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-NASTYNUMBER\Software\blah"

Comment: Splendid! I just didn't think of that... Not my brightest moment, hihi.